# Trouble inserting BST node into a List node

Tags: c++, list

I'm creating a customer loyalty program type code using a Linked list and BST's. It uses a list of loyalty programs, each node containing a BST of customer ID's. Currently I am attempting to create a function that searches the list for a loyalty program, once found (creates if not) adds the customer ID into the BST of that node. However when testing, im running into a reading violation on the insert new list node (insert_at_front)  function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ive tried altering the function type of the find_list function and creating wrapper functions for it as I have previously done with similar functions for BST's, but I keep getting lost in the code and it seems to break it more.

```
list.h header file:
typedef struct listNode {
    char* name; //Name of company
    BST *customer;  //Tree of customer ID's
    struct listNode *next; //Pointer for next compnay
} *ListNodePtr;
```

```
void option_insert(List *self) {
    char* input_loyalty;
    int input_ID;

    printf("What loyalty program do you wish to add a customer to?  \n");
    scanf("%s", &input_loyalty);
    printf("What is the customer ID \n");
    scanf("%d", &input_ID);

    find_list(self, input_loyalty, input_ID);
}

void find_list(List *self, char* data, int ID) {
    ListNodePtr current = self->head;

    if (current != NULL) {
        if (current->name == data) {
            insert_bst(self->head->customer, ID);
        }
        else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    else {                          
        insert_at_front(self, data);
        insert_bst(self->head->customer, ID);
    }

}

void insert_at_front(List *self, char* data) {
    int n = strlen(data);
    ListNodePtr new_node = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(new_node->name, data);

    new_node->next = self->head;
    self->head = new_node;
}
```

I have included the functions being utilised in the problem but note that they are separated in different .c files. (however this should cause no difference) and I can certainly provide more code if needed

Comment: Any reason it has to be a linked list and not a `std::vector`?

Comment: It is part of a project for school, that requires it use these data structures @Chipster

Comment: Oh. That makes sense.

Comment: Follow up question, since you're in C++, is there a reason you're using `malloc()` and not C++'s `new` keyword? Also school?

Comment: `ListNodePtr new_node = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));` Can you please explain this line? It looks very wrong, but maybe I miss something.

Comment: @Chipster `malloc()` is just what we've learnt in this course, they haven't taught us `new` for some reason. Also if you mean which school, its UTAS, in Aus.

Comment: @dyukha This line may also be wrong but it is supposed to create just enough memory for the user inputed word

Comment: Ok, so then you should do the following: allocate memory to store `listNode` (so it should be smth like `sizeof(struct listNode)`). Then you should allocate memory for `new_node->name` like you did (BTW, it should be `n+1`, not `n`).

Comment: Are you sure it's a C++ course? [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is probably in your use of `malloc()`. You are creating memory based off the size of data, and not the size of a struct.

I should also mention that if you are using C++ (and not C) it is probably better to learn how to use the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/new-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019) keyword instead.

Anyway, if you still decide to use malloc, try this instead:

```
void insert_at_front(List *self, char* data) {
    int n = strlen(data);
    ListNodePtr new_node = malloc(sizeof(listNode)); // note, we're using the size of a node instead
    new_node->name = malloc(n * sizeof(char)); // now, we need to allocate the string too.

    strlcpy(new_node->name, data, n); // if you want to use a "secure" copy

    new_node->next = self->head;
    self->head = new_node;
}
```